# How to embed a word document in .net

Tags: c#, resources, embedded-resource

I'm trying to embed a word document in my project. This document will be used as a template by a specific library.

I have added the file using `Project | Add Existing Item...`, I have also set its **Build Action** to ***Resource*** and its **Copy to Output Directory** to ***Do Not Copy***.

Now in my code behind I'm doing this to access the file:

```
var template = DocX.Load("pack://application:,,,/doc1.docx");
```

But I'm getting an exeption: XamlParseException occured.

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the stream to the document from the resources using the[`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as in the example below:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = "MyNamespace.doc1.docx"  // check your resource name.
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
{
    var template = DocX.Load(stream);
}
```

Also check out this information: [How to embed and access resources by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292)

And also change the Build Action to Embedded Resource.

Comment: Thanks Alex but now I'm getting TargetInvocationException wan unhandled exception.

Comment: I have added the resource to my main project folder. I debugged `stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)` returns null.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown and what is the inner exception? The convention for the resource name is namespace.resource, so if your project is called MyProject, `var resourceName = "MyProject.doc1.docx";`

Comment: My project name is WriteToWord so I have done like this: `var resourceName = "WriteToWord.doc1.docx";` It seems that `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)` returns null.

Comment: Documentation states, that it only returns **null** if: "no resources were specified during compilation or if the resource is not visible to the caller." In which assembly / project is the resource embedded?

Comment: I uploaded an screenshot. Maybe this will help.

Comment: I changed the `Build Action` to `Embedded Resource`. Now it is working. Thanks